# How to get a Call Hierarchy in VB .NET and Visual Studio Community Edition

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone recommend a good tool for building a call hierarchy list?

I'm using VB .NET with Visual Studio Community Edition.

The Enterprise Edition has a tool available to do this, but that edition is not available to me.

The Call Hierarchy window only shows who calls you when using VB - it doesn't show who you call.

What I need to do is to select a Function or Sub and get a list of what it calls, and then what they call, and so on right down to the bottom of the hierarchy (ideally ignoring standard VB functions).

I want to pull some code out into a separate DLL but I need to know what must accompany it for it to compile and execute cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools in Community edition, which can help you to do what you need:

- Call Stack (runtime only)
- Call Hierarchy
- Find All References

Third party tools like CodeRush for Roslyn can do little more, like Debug Visualizer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately Call Hierarchy in VS only shows who calls you when working in VB (it shows both directions in other languages), so it's no use if you are wanting (say) to isolate a function but need to take with it everything it calls, and what they call down to the bottom of the tree. Similarly Find All References is effectively going up the tree and not down the tree.

Comment: @SteveM By visualizing what is called by what, result will be tangled spider web where everything calls everything.

Comment: I can imagine that to be true in many cases. In my case I wrote the software so I know that will not be the case :)